# Using AVAudioPlayer in a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio

I have a UIViewController subclass for a game with an AVAudioPlayer to play a song in the background. In my viewDidLoad method, I have the following code:

```
[super viewDidLoad];

...

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval: 0.03 target: self selector: @selector(gameLoop) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];

NSString *path = @"path-to-song";
self->audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path] error: NULL];
audioPlayer.delegate = self;
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = - 1;
[audioPlayer play];
```

gameLoop is a method which contains the core logic for the game. When I run the app on my testing device, the audio plays, but it appears to be frozen, and gameLoop doesn't run normally. If I remove all the AVAudioPlayer code, the game works fine otherwise. It seems like there's some threading issue here that I'm not aware of. Any ideas?

Comment: What format is the audio file in? (Just checking it's not a 44Mhz AIFF file or a very high bitrate MP3 or anything.)

Comment: Why would that make a difference? The audio plays fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving your AVAudioPlayer code into a method and running it in a background thread like so:

```
- (void)playSong:(NSURL*)atURL
{
   self->audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: atURL error: NULL];
   audioPlayer.delegate = self;
   audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = - 1;
   [audioPlayer play];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   ...

   NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: @"path-to-song"]
   [self performSelectorInBackground: @selector(playSong:) withObject: url];
}
```

Comment: This seems to work in the simulator. Not sure if the audio's actually playing as I'm on the Mac over RDP. I will test it on an actual iPhone device tomorrow and see how it goes. Your code looks like it should work fine though, thank you. One small thing, I think you meant to put `@selector(playSong:)` on the bottom line since playSong takes one argument. If it works, +1 and accepted answer. ;)

Comment: Yep, worked perfectly on both the simulator and device. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

Remove timer repeats:Yes to repeats:NO.May be its the problem.Because your gameLoop method would be called after every 0.3 seconds

Comment: That's the intention - hence game**Loop** ;)